# VCR configuration issue for cypress-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cypress, vcr

I followed the instruction in the README: https://github.com/shakacode/cypress-on-rails to set up cypress-on-rails (and it itself runs fine) but when I try to configure VCR for it (following the cypress-on-rails instructions).

I keep getting the following error in cypress specifically:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-on-rails/support/index.js'
```

My question is where does this mysterious cypress-on-rails folder supposed to reside because it seems like I can't find it and webpack can't find it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the cypress-on-rails [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-on-rails)

```
yarn add cypress-on-rails --dev
```